# make excel show trailing zeros in html table

Tags: .net, excel, html-table, zero

How can I show the trailing zeros in an html table viewed in excel?

I've examined the html in notepad++, so I know they're there.

The table is being built in .ashx with a .xls extension.

**specifics**

I'd like the numbers to be automatically formatted for the user.

I'd like to still be able to manipulate the numbers as numbers (if displaying as text).

**how I'm building table in ashx**

```
If sqlDataset.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
    context.Response.BufferOutput = False
    Dim response As HttpResponse = context.Response

    context.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=Total Quote Sheet " & DateTime.Now() & ".xls")
    context.Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel"
    Dim outputHTML As String

    Using sw As StringWriter = New StringWriter
        Using ht As HtmlTextWriter = New HtmlTextWriter(sw)

            Dim table As New Table

            Dim headings = {"Article Number", "Quantity Quote", "SAP Supplier #", "Cost Code", "Unit Cost", "Extended Cost", "SAP Description", "Status"}
            Dim HeaderRow As New TableRow
            HeaderRow.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.White
            For Each heading As String In headings
                Dim Cell As New TableCell
                Cell.Text = heading
                Cell.BorderWidth = 1
                Cell.BorderColor = Drawing.Color.Black
                Cell.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Solid
                Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#003797")
                HeaderRow.Cells.Add(Cell)
            Next

            table.Rows.Add(HeaderRow)

            For u As Integer = 0 To sqlDataset.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1

                Dim DataRow As New TableRow
                Dim dataColumnNames = {"AN", "QB", "SSN", "CC", "UC", "EC", "AD", "BAI"}
                For Each dataColumnName As String In dataColumnNames
                    Dim Cell As New TableCell
                    Cell.Text = sqlDataset.Tables(0).Rows(u).Field(Of Object)(dataColumnName)
                    Cell.BorderWidth = 1
                    Cell.BorderColor = Drawing.Color.Black
                    Cell.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Solid
                    If dataColumnName = "BAI" Then
                        Select Case sqlDataset.Tables(0).Rows(u).Field(Of Object)(dataColumnName)
                            Case "U"
                                Cell.Text = "Undecided"
                            Case "A"
                                Cell.Text = "Accepted"
                            Case "R"
                                Cell.Text = "Rejected"
                        End Select
                    End If
                    DataRow.Cells.Add(Cell)
                Next

                table.Rows.Add(DataRow)
            Next
            table.RenderControl(ht)
            outputHTML = sw.ToString()
            context.Response.Write(outputHTML)
        End Using
    End Using

End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to display the values as text.   There are three ways to do this, one is to set the cell format to text, use the text() function, or if you are importing it you can change the data type to text.

Comment: i'm sorry, i should've been more specific.  I'd like this to be automatic for users (client).  also, can i use the `text()` function inside html tables?  if so, can the numbers still be manipulated as numbers?

Comment: So if I am a client am I opening your spreadsheet or am I just making my own spreadsheet and importing your data?  And no I don't think that you can put an Excel formula and have Excel import it as a formula but if you put a ' character before your number it would consider it text, although it would probably still display that character

Comment: I use an `HTTPHandler` to generate an html table.  I simply slap on an `.xls` extension.  The user opens the html table in excel automatically and can manipulate it from there.  It looks just like a real excel spreadsheet except for a ridiculous warning that I can't figure out how to turn off.  Yes, it's sad, but this is actually the recommended excel export method from MS.  They actually recommend *against* using built-in excel libraries from building true excel files.  lol

Comment: Can you post what you have so I can see exactly what you mean?